# Check duplicate and return the next value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007

Here is my explanation of my problems. I have 30k rows with 2 columns as below:

- Column A: code. Form: AA.
- Column B: code. Form: AA-i. With `i` run from `a` to `z`, then `1` - `100`.

I would like to find the next AA-i, and do not duplicate with any AA-i in column B.

How can I do it? I really need help. Much thanks any idea to help a lots.

[image: Example]

Comment: It sounds like there may be a language barrier getting in the way clearly explaining your problem. No need be alarmed, this is when `photos with sample data` help. Please add a screen shot showing your starting point with sample data and desired output

Comment: Hi. I have already add picture to show my problem. Sr about my bad english anyway.

Comment: *"I would like to find the next AA-i"* The next `AA-i` to what? What is your current `AA-i`? Is it always `AA` or will there also be others? Please give us more information about what the overall goal of all this is. Therefore [edit] your question.

Comment: Hi Peh. Thanks for your help. AA will not change. I want to find the next code. For example in my picture, if column B have: AA-a, AA-b, AA-c. I want the result is AA-d, and make sure AA-d not available in column B. In onother case, if column B have AA-a...AA-z, aslo have AA-1 to AA-10 (because after a-z was gernerated, number will be used), my expexted result is AA-11.

Comment: Are the values in column B always sorted this way or could they be mixed up like `AA-a, AA-b, AA-15, AA-3, AA-c` etc? And are they continous, that means if there is a `AA-c` that there **must** be a `AA-a, AA-b` already? • If they are sorted and continous, you would just need find the last used cell in column B (google) and use the [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) with `-` as delimiter and analyse the second part of the split result to generate the next value. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return A-12 next in your result column and A-13 once A-12 is used. If so you can use the formula in your result column : It will give you the next AA- followed by number and checks the value if it was used earlier...

=IF(("AA-"& VALUE(RIGHT(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1),(LEN(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1)))-(FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1),"-","@")))))+1)=A2:A4,"AA-"& VALUE(RIGHT(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1),(LEN(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1)))-(FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1),"-","@")))))+2,"AA-"& VALUE(RIGHT(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1),(LEN(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1)))-(FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1),"-","@")))))+1)

The formula gone very messy so let me explain : 
Find the last entry in your column : =OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1)
find position of "-" in string : =FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1),"-","@"))
find length of your string : =LEN(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,1,1))
Use right and valu function to find out the last number used.
add one to the result and concatenate "AA-" with the result.
use IF array function to find if the final output was used earlier and return next number if true else use the same.

DO not FOrget to press CTRL+SHFT+Enter as it is an array Formula
Assumption that your data is sorted as you have shown above.

I hope it resolved your query.